# How to add Phone Number Column field in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

First Sorry for my Grammar. Not my mother tongue and also if this Question is not the correct forum please just direct me to the correct forum.

Ok! I bought a theme from envanto and i'm trying to customize some of the field

I want to add Phone Number column field on top of location. I already made the code and its actually working but after i click publish...it seems working but when im finding the phone number field i cant find them.

I have to add the link for better understanding. the site is on trial so you can try for your self what i mean about the " phone number field Issue".

The code  is this below

```
<fieldset class="input-title">

    <label for="edit-title" class="control-label"><?php _e('Location', 'agrg') ?></label>
    <input type="text" id="post_location" name="post_location" value="" size="12" maxlength="110" class="form-text required">

</fieldset>
<!--Post Phone Number-->
<fieldset class="input-title">

    <label for="edit-title" class="control-label"><?php _e('Phone', 'agrg') ?></label>
    <input type="text" id="post_phone" name="post_phone" value="" size="12" maxlength="110" class="form-text required">

</fieldset>
<!--/Post Phone Number-->
```

Comment: Basically I copy the code Phone number to the above code " post_location" (the website which has a problem is "http://bintahan.com/new-ad-2/new-ad/ "

Comment: I also add this code:update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_phone', wp_kses($_POST['post_phone'], $allowed));